# Auto Increment in FLuent Nhibernate and PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate

I`m a newbie in Fluent Nhibernate.

I have a [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) database and what I want is a generated id with auto increment.
I have not seen feature auto increment in PostgreSQL and I understand that to use auto increment in PostgreSQL I have to create a sequence.

Is there another way besides sequences?

If `create sequence` is the only way, can you tell me how I should mapping it?
I tried to use this and had no success:

```
mapping.Id(x => x.Id, "id").GeneratedBy.Sequence("hibernate-sequence");
```

I have created `hibernate-sequence` before using it.

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strange, but with your code an insertion works fine, if you call `Save(Object)` instead of `SaveOrUpdate(Object)`

Edit #1

That's what worked for me.

Entity:

```
public class Human
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HumanMap : ClassMap<Human>
{
    public HumanMap()
    {
        this.Id(x => x.ID).CustomSqlType("Serial").GeneratedBy.Native();
        this.Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

And configuration with schema export:

```
static ISessionFactory CreateSF()
{
    return Fluently
    .Configure()
    .Database(PostgreSQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=fnhtest;User=postgres;Password=password"))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => { new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true); })
    .BuildSessionFactory(); 
}
```

Comment: If `Save` works and `SaveOrUpdate` does not... It means that NH have problem with connection between C# collection elements and SQL table rows. Probably NH cannot find elements because wrong PK assignment.

Comment: incorrect, PostgreSQLConfiguration.Standard does not work with GeneratedBy.Native(), use PostgreSQLConfiguration.PostgreSQL82 which is latest (NHibernate version: 4.0.0.4000).

Answer (score 1):

> I have not seen feature auto increment in PostgreSQL

That's the SERIAL datatype mentioned by Frank.

Just create the colum in question as SERIAL and you have an auto-increment column:

```
CREATE TABLE the_table (
  id serial not null primary key,
  other_column varchar(20), 
  ...
);
```

Then you need to annotate that columns as an "auto increment" in Hibernate (as I don't use Hibernate, I can't tell you how exactly that is done).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the datatype [SERIAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).

Comment: what I do write in entity?can you explain completed?